# Python Float rounding errors

Tags: python, python-2.7

When using list comprehension expression:

```
[x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 5)]
```

I expect to get a list like this:

```
[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

However I instead I get this:

```
[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4]
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It's only a dup if you ignore the fact that the OP mistakenly thought the list comprehension was part of the problem. The question is whether future searchers/readers are likely to have the same mistaken impression.

Comment: Step 1 or 2 of trying to solve this question should be "try it without a list comprehension to see if the results hold", @abarnert, so I believe the duplicate proposal is correct.

Comment: @abarnert: The problem is still the floating point rounding error. Someone else thinking they have the same problem will find this question, then be pointed to the dupe question to see that floating point errors can occur without list comprehensions too. Which is the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

floats are inherently imprecise in pretty much every language

if you need exact precision use the [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) class

```
from decimal import Decimal
print Decimal("0.3")
```

if you just need them to look pretty just use format strings when displaying
eg :

```
"%0.2f"%2.030000000000034
```

if you want to compare them use some threshold

```
if num1 - num2 < 1e-3 : print "Equal Enough For Me!"
```

**see abarnert's comments on thresholding ... this is a very simplified example for a more indepth explanation of epsilon thresholding one article I found is here http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm

Additional Reading:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (for a detailed explanation)

http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/ (basic tutorial for working with floats in general)

Comment: Exactly - this has nothing to do with the list comprehension.  (Well, I'm not sure I'd call python floats "accurate" to any specific precision without a clearer definition of "accurate".)  You get the same imprecise result if you just directly evaluate 0.1 * 3.

Comment: "floats are accurate up to 9 places after the decimal" is wrong. For example, `float(1<<64)+.1 == float(1<<64)` is `True`—it's not even accurate to _1_ place after the decimal.

Comment: Also, similarly, if you don't have some out-of-band way of knowing the scale you care about, you often need something like `num1 - num2 < 1e-3 * max(num1, num2)` (or `gmean` or some other function, depending on the case). And of course this only works for positive numbers, because you forgot the `abs`. I think it would be better to link to some discussion of epsilon thresholding or error analysis than to try to explain it in one line.

Comment: your right ... removed wrong part ... I coulda sworn I read somewhere that python guaranteed floats up to X precision ... but meh

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Up to X precision means the number of _significant_ digits, not the number of _fractional_ digits. Also, Python's docs speak a bit loosely: if you take subnormals into account, the number of significant digits in an IEEE double can be less than 1.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Also, you might want to add the tutorial link and Goldberg link to the answer, so this one answer is sufficient without people having to read the later ones as well.

Comment: done :) as always good suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension does not matter.

```
>>> 3 * 0.1
0.30000000000000004
>>> 2 * 0.1
0.2
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

More information about Python float and floating point arithmetic - [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension is irrelevant, this is purely an issue with floating-point numbers.  For an extremely detailed answer you should give this article a read: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html